# Adding buttons from a dictionary in PyQt

Tags: python, dictionary, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm trying to make a bunch of buttons from a dictionary. In my case have to use a scrollbar, cause there's more than 200 keys. I've tried to use example in this link: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14159337/pyqt-put-scrollbars-in-this). However, no success

Here is my code:

```
import sys
import json
import time 
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Form(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)
        self.scrollArea = QtGui.QScrollArea(self)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtGui.QWidget(self.scrollArea)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 380, 247))
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea)
        self.verticalLayoutScroll =
        QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)

        self.make_form()


    def make_form(self):
        with open('list.json', 'r') as f:
            data = json.load(f)
        for item in data.keys():
            button_name = item
            button = QtGui.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
            button.setText(button_name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Form()
    form.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add the buttons to `self.verticalLayoutScroll`:

```
self.verticalLayoutScroll.addWidget(button)
```

Complete code:

```
import sys
import json
import time 
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class Form(QtGui.QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)
        self.scrollArea = QtGui.QScrollArea(self)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtGui.QWidget(self.scrollArea)
        self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 380, 247))
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea)
        self.verticalLayoutScroll = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)

        self.make_form()


    def make_form(self):
        with open('list.json', 'r') as f:
            data = json.load(f)
            for item in data.keys():
                button_name = item
                button = QtGui.QPushButton(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
                self.verticalLayoutScroll.addWidget(button)
                button.setText(button_name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = Form()
    form.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot!